# Error while creating package for uwp

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm developing an app with C# & Visual Studio 2015 Community for windows 10.

I was trying to create a package for store (appxupload file) but it gives me error:

```
Loading assembly "C:\Users\Ramtin\.nuget\packages\System.Private.Uri\4.0.0\runtimes\win8-aot\lib\netcore50\System.Private.Uri.dll" failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.



Invalid Resx file. String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: suffix  MyAPP   C:\Users\Ramtin\.nuget\packages\System.Private.Uri\4.0.0\runtimes\win8-aot\lib\netcore50\System.Private.Uri.dll
```

[image: http://s7.picofile.com/file/8241354442/Capture.JPG]

how can I solve this?

note: I have individual account for develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't received this error myself, but you should verify that you have the latest Windows 10 SDK installed and latest VS2015 updates.

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 just came out last week: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx
- When you launch VS2015, check the notifications area on the top right for any newly available updates.
- When you click File | New | Project in VS2015, check the list of Universal project template types and look to see if there's a list item that prompts you to download the latest SDK.

My screenshot below shows the template types and also the (optional) Template10 that I have available to me. If you don't have the latest SDK, you should see an additional entry that prompts you to download the latest SDK (as opposed to creating a new project)

*After verifying that you have the latest of everything, try generating a new package again and please comment below to let us know whether it worked (or if you are still getting errors).*

[image: Windows 10 Project templates]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's great, updated to Update 2 and works fine! i had a problem with opening Package.appxmanifest and it gives me Stopped working when I open it the  Package.appxmanifest , but after updated to update 2, everything works well. thanks alot

Comment: That's great to hear! :)

Comment: It also fixed my build error in 2022 https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15294